# How to correctly put labels on one line

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have three `UILabel` with different font and I want to put then on one line.

The problem is that as the text length of those label is not fixed, I have to change the location of the second and the third label according to the text length of the label before, otherwise the text will be overlapped.

I plan to set the location according to the text length of the label before and I have to recognize the uppercase and the lowercase. I have to consider more if I use other language.

I want to know is there a better method to solve this problem, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CGSize size = [@"SomeString" sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:20.0]];
CGFloat width = size.width;
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into the CoreText Framework. You'll be able to have much more control over your text characteristics than using UILabels.

Developer Reference:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/CoreText_Programming/Introduction/Introduction.html

Tutorial:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/4147/how-to-create-a-simple-magazine-app-with-core-text